# Why can I not ClassRegistry::init() my CakePHP model?

Tags: php, database, cakephp, model

I'm not new to frameworks and work with Symfony quite often but I have a legacy version of CakePHP 2.4 that I must maintain for now and am having an issue. My code is this:

```
function aff($user=null,$pid=null) {
    if (empty($user) || empty($pid)) $this->redirect('/');
    $userModel =& ClassRegistry::init('User');
    $productModel =& ClassRegistry::init('Product');
    $granularModel =& ClassRegistry::init('Granular');

    $this->autoRender = false;
    $temp = array(
        'user' => $user,
        'pid' => $pid
    );
    $granularModel->save($temp);
}
```

This is a function inside my controller. The User and Product models are being ClassRegistry::init just fine and work correctly BUT my Granular model causes the page to load with a message of "The requested address XXXX was not found on this server." Here is my model:

```
<?php
    class Granular extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'Granular';
    }
?>
```

Why is it causing the route not to be found? If I put an "echo 'Hello'; exit();" right after the line $productModel =& ClassRegistry::init('Product'); it loads the route just fine. I feel lost. Please help. TIA

Comment: And what happens when you put the stop after the `Granular` init line? Have you tested that it's that line that triggers it? In any case, enable debug mode and try again, also check the logs. If you don't find anything, hook up a debugger and set a breakpoint at that line, and then manually step through the call stack to figure what exactly happens.

Comment: @ndm if I put a breakpoint after the Granular line I get the 404 error that the route isnt found. The loaded in the User and Product lines works fine. It's the Granular line that is breaking it. I'll try debug mode. How do you set that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason today after turning on Configure::write('debug', 1); in app/config/core.php, it suddenly started working. I am guessing at this point that it must have been a caching issue of some sort.